# How do I compare characters in two strings? python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a shift cipher. So I will shift all the letters by two.

Here is the code I've written:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   alphabetarr = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
   alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   plaintextt = input("Enter your plaintext: ")
for i in plaintextt:
    for y in alphabet:
        if plaintextt(i)== alphabet(y):
            if y>24:
                y=0
                ciphertext = ciphertext + alphabet(y+2)
            else:
                ciphertext = ciphertext + alphabet(y + 2)
print(ciphertext)
```

I get the error:

```
    if plaintextt(i)== alphabet(y):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: You need to use brackets like so `if plaintextt[i] == alphabet[y]:` when grabbing values from a list (or a string) using an index number. Of course `i` and `y` in your code aren't index numbers, they represent the character you want already so just change it to `if i == y:`

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. I've tried all variations of brackets all with errors. I get this error:  if plaintextt[i] == alphabet[y]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: i and y are meant to be index numbers. How can I get the actual index number? I need it so I can tell the index to go back to zero if it exceeds the array length

Answer (score 0):

simple mistake your `i` and `y` are not numbers but the values themselves. Try:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   alphabetarr = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
   alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
   plaintextt = input("Enter your plaintext: ")
for i in range(len(plaintextt)):
    for y in range(len(alphabet)):
        if plaintextt[i]== alphabet[y]:
            if y>24:
                y=0
                ciphertext = ciphertext + alphabet[y+2]
            else:
                ciphertext = ciphertext + alphabet[y + 2]
print(ciphertext)
```

Comment: It works. This + change the brackets to square and it'll work. Thanks!

Comment: You welcome. Please mark this as the answer for future coders

Comment: @CodePal, as mentioned, you'll need to change to square brackets to make the syntax valid (e.g. `alphabet[y]`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with some clarifying pointers.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    shift = 2
    alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    plaintext = input("Enter your plaintext: ")
    ciphertext = ""
    for i in plaintext:
        for idx, y in enumerate(alphabet):
            if i == y:
                if idx > len(alphabet) - shift - 1:
                    idx = idx - len(alphabet)
                ciphertext = ciphertext + alphabet[idx + shift]

    print(ciphertext)
```

`alphabet` and `alphabetarr` are virtually the same thing since string are just lists of characters in Python. You can use `for idx, y in enumerate(alphabet)` to get the index number and correct element simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a function utilizing the [modulo operator (`%`)](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase), [`str.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase), [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) and [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase


def shift_cipher_encode(s: str, k: int) -> str:
  result = []
  for c in s:
    if c.isalpha():
      current_index = ord(c.lower()) - ord('a')
      new_index = (current_index + k) % 26
      new_c = ascii_lowercase[new_index]
      result.append(new_c if c.islower() else new_c.upper())
    else:
      result.append(c)
  return ''.join(result)


def main() -> None:
  plain_text = input("Enter your plaintext: ")
  print(shift_cipher_encode(plain_text, 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter your plaintext: Hello World
Jgnnq Yqtnf
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in the code. This logic should work for you

```
ciphertext = ''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    plaintextt = input("Enter your plaintext: ")
    for i in range(len(plaintextt)):
        for y in range(len(alphabet)):
            if plaintextt[i]== alphabet[y]:
                if y>23:
                    ciphertext = ciphertext + alphabet[y%24]
                else:
                    ciphertext = ciphertext + alphabet[y + 2]
    print(ciphertext)
```

If you further face any issues, please let me know. Cheers :)